# What kind of difficulties you've faced with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As any other framework Hibernate impose some restrictions. One of a very popular interview questions is:

> "What kind of difficulties you've faced with Hibernate?"

**For instance:**

1. Lazy one-2-one bidirectional is impossible.
2. Lazy collection loading after session close. That happens when you use DAO + Spring transactions. [You can read here about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298594/what-are-some-common-problems-with-hibernate-persistence).
3. Troubles with concurrent update on clustered application
4. [N + 1 selecting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

**Question:** may you supplement this humble list please?

**P.S.**
I don't  mean those difficulties when you are newcomer in Hibernate and don't now how to map many-2-many. I mean those difficulties that faced every experienced programmer while using this framework.

Answer (score 1):

I would add :

- Managing the session lifecycle and transaction demarcation (particulary with RIA apps using long-conversation scope which cannot be managed by the container)
- collection management and performance ([Collection mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections))
- [The JPA hashCode() / equals() dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031614/the-jpa-hashcode-equals-dilemma)